# Truncate date while filtering date within dategridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, .net-4.0

I am trying to filter `DataGridView` bounded from `DataTable` source`by using`DateTimePicker`

my problem is that column `DATETIME` has date and time and I just want to use only date without time example

```
select cast(DATETIME as DATE) from table_name
```

I tried below but I get error message says

> the expression contains undefined function call cast()

so How i can truncate the date ?

```
(MyDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("cast(DATETIME as DATE)= '{0}'", DpickerEntryDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

all event code

```
        if (DpickerEntryDate.Value.Date <= DateTime.Today.Date)
        {
            (MyDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("cast(DATETIME as DATE) = '{0}'", DpickerEntryDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
        }
        else if (DpickerEntryDate.Value.Date > DateTime.Today.Date)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not use future date", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: A Date is a value - how would you truncate 34592824343?  You do need to pass an expression though

Comment: Another way of thinking of `"cast(ENDATETIME as DATE) = '{0}'"` is `ENDATETIME >= DateIAmInterestedIn AND ENDATETIME < (DateIAmInterestedIn + 1)`. _This means you can solve it **without** having to remove the time component from `ENDATETIME`._

Comment: @mjwills ummm u make the time are equal in both date so it existence will make no difference am I understand right?

Comment: @Plutonix I did not get it plase sir more explanation

Comment: `ummm u make the time are equal in both date so it existence will make no difference am I understand right?` I am pointing out that the code example I give is equivalent to yours **without the need for CAST**. Let's look at an example if `ENDATETIME` was 1st Jan 2018 3pm, and you want to check it correctly matches 1st Jan 2018. You could, as you are trying, strip off the time. Then 1st Jan 2018 == 1st Jan 2018. _Or_ you could ask 'Is 1st Jan 2018 3pm >= 1st Jan 2018 (yes it is) and < 2nd Jan 2018 (yes it is)?'. Make sense?

Answer (score -1):

Don't "truncate" the date.  Let the date flow into your C# code as a DateTime, then in form initialization code, *Style* the column by fetching the column from the `DataGridView` (a `DataGridViewColumn` from the `Columns` property of the `DataGridView` and setting the `DefaultCellStyle`

```
column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = //Some format from DateTime.ToString(string format)
```

Comment: I can't I want to display to user the datetime but ignore it only when filtering data

Comment: Where are you getting that Cast() error.  This code works for me in SQL Server Management Studio: `declare @someDateTime DateTime = GetDate();
declare @someDate Date = Cast(@someDateTime as Date);
print @someDate;`  It prints today's date.

Comment: @Flydog57 It is being run as a RowFilter against a DataTable. i.e. in memory.

Comment: How about formatting the entered date into a format that the filter expression syntax likes.  For example, this is a filter expression statement: `dataView.RowFilter = "Date = #2008-12-31#" `.  So format your entered date so that it looks like `"#YYYY-MM-DD#`, concatenate a '"Date ="' to the front and go to town.  Is that what you are asking about?